# Returning specific values of a struct

Tags: c++

Is it possible (albeit probably not good practice) to immediately set values of a struct from a function? 
for example :

```
typedef struct 
{
    bool success;
    std::string returnString;
} functionReturn;

functionReturn go(std::string word[])
{
    functionReturn returnStruct;
    ...

    return returnStruct;
}


int main()
{
    std::string word[4];
    ... //assign values to word
    std::string returnedString = go(word).returnString //will this work?
}
```

Is that possible or do I actually have to assign it to another functionReturn and pull out the string value from it?

Comment: Hint: try things first! I have a `test` directory where I write small samples of code that I want to see if and how they work. It's very useful! Another option is to try it out on something like [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: Why not try yourself!

Comment: @sftrabbit +1 in general (also, there are online compilers like [ideone](http://ideone.com/)). Nevertheless, this can be skewed by compiler bugs and/or extensions.

Comment: I didn't know about ideone, I do now, Thanks!

Comment: note that your typedef struct syntax is usually done in C, and disturbing and unnecessary in C++

Comment: @sftrabbit, +1 and I follow the same practice for both my own use and for pasting SO code that is broken.  I have `testcpp` and `testcsharp` open pretty much most of the time.  And LINQPad.

Comment: @sftrabbit:  Just because something compiles & appears to work doesn't mean it's legitimate.

Comment: @JohnDibling It's a good suggestion though. If it still seems suspect, then they can ask, but they clearly didn't think much beyond "hmm, I wonder if this is possible".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's perfectly possible; it's not different from calling a member function of a returned object, which is quite normal:

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << "file" << i;
std::ifstream f(s.str().c_str());  //notice calls here
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the `typedef struct {...} name;` idiom in C++.  This is a holdover from C and has no value in C++.  Just use the standard technique: `struct name {...};`

There is nothing *technically* wrong with doing what you're doing.  Just be careful you don't return a reference to a local, or anything like that.  You're not here.

In fact, you could have a method that does something with the parameters and returns a reference to the object, and then chain together method calls, like this:

```
struct functionReturn
{
  functionReturn& doSomething() { return * this; }
  functionReturn& doSomethingElse() { return * this; }
};

int main()
{
  functionReturn fr;
  fr.doSomething().doSomethingElse();
}
```

This is also valid.  It's called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).  The question is not weather it's valid, but if it's semantically clear and maintainable.  Some people consider constructs like this to be elegant and concise.  Others consider it to be an abomination.  Count me in the latter group.  Decide for yourself.

Comment: Indeed!  Though method chaining can be useful in, say, LINQ in C# where it is clear the output of one method becomes the input of another, but yes - I try and avoid it if all they are doing is returning `this` rather than something more interesting :)